# Getting gobbledegook from SQL server on mysql turns out its a old codepage.Why is it set up like this? How do I change the defaults?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, codepages

I'm writing a new project that utilises MySQL , There is no problem with the app I'm working on, but when the app recives the output from my sql server it immediately rejects it as null. When accessing my SQL server on port 3306 I am getting strange garbled messages back as well as the short message 'packets out of order.' In my setup I have, MAMP, Docker, Apache server and PHP. I can access each service on its respective port just fine.

1) I have looked into this by running console in the browser which reports the text being incorrectly formatted to something that isn't utf-8

2) I have followed this guide
https://medium.com/@manish_demblani/breaking-out-from-the-mysql-character-set-hell-24c6a306e1e5 and the results that my sql server have churned out are as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGFEV.png)

My question is this. Why is MySQL set up in this strange fashion? Why is it presenting in CP850 /DOS/ Latin? Are there no defaults/config files to change or is it done through windows somewhere

Comment: It seems you somehow messed up the *client* configuration (connection string,  `[client]`-section of your cnf file (on the system that you started the mysql console on), ...). It tells your server to send data in cp850. Not sure why you would get packets out of order, maybe you have an additional underlying problem (very old library maybe?), but I'd start there. It's unclear: did you follow the blog post and *then* had problems, or was that a solution attempt? In any case, try to focus your attention on the client. Try to undo changes you made. MySQL uses utf8 by default for a long time now.

Comment: I followed the guide after it became apparent that there was a problem and after I had thought about the logical process and ascertained that the code page might be the problem 
That’s an amazing bit of information, many thanks :) I didn’t know about the presence of the MySQL.ini or Cnf files, it has opened up a whole new world of options for me although the goobledygook still stands my original question about the configuration file and it’s location has been answered. I am quite happy to take this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you somehow messed up the client configuration (connection string, [client]-section of your cnf file (on the system that you started the mysql console on), ...). It tells your server to send data in cp850. Not sure why you would get packets out of order, maybe you have an additional underlying problem (very old library maybe?), but I'd start there. It's unclear: did you follow the blog post and then had problems, or was that a solution attempt? In any case, try to focus your attention on the client. Try to undo changes you made. MySQL uses utf8 by default for a long time now. – Solarflare